# What's the Subject in: 'And up here in the corner is me'

Tags: subjects, subject-verb-inversion, deixis, locative-inversion

If two people are looking at a photo, and one of them pointing out the different people  says:

> And up here in the corner is me.

... what is the Subject of the sentence?

The phrase *up here in the corner* feels like a Locative Complement. It is tempting to see this as a case of subject-dependent inversion like *On the  corner is a cafe*. However, the NP *me* has accusative case and the verb is third person singular. The sentence isn't:

- *And up here in the corner am me.

Also, if and only if, 'me' is not the Subject, what type of use of the verb *BE* is this? If *me* is an internal Complement of the verb, then this doesn't seem to be a specifying, ascriptive or locative use in the normal sense (*me* is not a description of *up in the corner*, neither is it a location. And the sentence does not mean "up in the corner = me").

And if, and only if, *me* is the Subject, why is *me* acceptable instead of *I*? Does *me* invariably take third person singular agreement of the verb?

Comment: How about *"And up here in the corner am I"*?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, so that case is nice and clear!

Comment: a) Knock knock.  --Who's there? It's me.  b)  Who wants ice cream? --Me!   c) Who's tidied this room up in my absence? --Why, that was little ole me.

Comment: @TimRomano +1 Yes, so in your first example, the Subject is *it*. In your second, *me* is accusative because there is no verb. In your third the Subject is the word *that*! :D

Comment: @Araucaria: "up here in the corner" seems to work like "that".  Do linguists distinguish between subjects and subject-pointers?

Comment: In 'Me and John went to the pictures last night', 'Me' is obviously part of the subject and thus used as nominative in spite of the obvious irregularities. It's the same here (substitute 'John'). What level of acceptability these nonstandard forms have is a different question. 'Me Tarzan' didn't cause too many heart attacks.

Comment: [Here's a set of tests](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/285246/15299)  for subjecthood. Does it agree? Yes, but only by default. Does it raise? Does it invert? Does it contract?

Comment: @JohnLawler  Nice link, but those don't seem to be helping with this case: Position: not helpful here because of possibility of sub-dep inversion. Agreement: not the best test, because, especially with *is* might be default, or inherited.Inversion: both results here are bad. Pronominasation, doesn't happen with *me*, so impossible to tell what *it* represents. Passive, equi, control: N/A. Contraction: not very good test really, but Complements also contract when there's Subject-Dependent inversion, so doesn't say much in this situation. Any other ideas?

Comment: _Over there in the corner is sposta be me?_ It raises. _What's over there in the corner is me._ It pseudo-clefts.

Comment: John's agreement test for subject works, and makes "me" the subject.  Compare "Up here in the corner are John and me."

Comment: @JohnLawler But in *On the corner is a cafe* the NP *a cafe* is the Subject. But we can still say *On the corner is supposed to be a cafe*! Can't just about anything pseudo-cleft?

Comment: Why do you say _a cafe_ is the subject? Is it determined by the Authorities? I'd say "subject" is not a terribly useful category here. And any constituent can pseudo-cleft, including subjects.

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, mainly because it's referred to as subject-dependent inversion. Secondly the verb agrees with cafe --> On the corner are some cafes.

Comment: There's something wrong with the "me" in the sentence.  What if you replace "me" with "Susan". And Susan is up here in the corner.

Comment: It's grammatical. It's just unusual; and we're discussing the ways it's unusual. One is not having an easily identifiable subject, and that raises the question of derived subjects and whether they "count" as subjects, which in turn raises the question of who's doing the counting and identifying, and why.

Comment: Maybe it's an instance of ellipsis: `[the one] up here in the corner is me`. The subject is left out because the adjective clause `[that is] up here` indicates its existence. The person's finger is yet another indicator.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Only 5 years late!, but I'm going to change my mind about this. On reflection. I think the subject is "up here in the corner" with "me" as predicative complement (as indicated by the pronoun being in the accusative case)

Answer (score 4):

I think that with *BE* we're probably better off subordinating the syntactics to the pragmatics and thinking of the two arguments on either side of the verb as something more like Topic and Comment, which are structurally assigned the syntactic roles Subject and Complement.

In that sort of context there's no problem with seeing a locative as *de facto* Subject:

> **A:** Do we want to eat at the table or in front of the TV?
>   **B:** At the table would be my choice.

And the conventional understanding of the existential construction is that *there* is the subject:

> **A:** Isn't there anybody might help?
>   **B:** Well, there's Jack.<sup>†</sup>

Alternatively, you may think of the locative as an attributive which has 'fused' with its head: *<s>this</s> up here on the corner*. The important thing is that *up here in the corner* is Old Information, and *me* is New Information.

On either analysis the understanding of pronominal case becomes clearer. In the vernacular—and to a growing extent even in the most formal registers—what we traditionally call the 'nominative' is not the form which marks the Subject but the form which marks a (unique, non-conjoint) Topic. All other uses call for the base form, hitherto called the 'accusative'.

In your example the locative is the Topic, assigned the syntactic role of Subject, and the pronoun is the Comment, assigned the syntactic role of Predicate Complement.

---

<sup>†</sup> Yeah, I know, the conventional understanding is that *there* is a pronoun, bleached of locativity. I think that's an unnecessary inference from the Subject role and suggest it's more parsimonious to think of it as the ordinary locative, bleached of deixis.

Comment: Hmm, but topicalisations seem to be topics but not Subjects! ;)

Comment: Topic, Subject, and Agent usually fall together prototypically, though they're capable of being separated (by Passive or Topicalization, for instance). And each of these category labels is really a bundle of features, which may not lead to a coherent choice in some situations. "Subject" is not a universal feature, anyway; ergative languages don't have it, for instance. So it's not surprising that it's not a useful (or discernible) feature in some situations.

Comment: Consider just for fun what the difference is between "I'm here", "Here I am", "Here am I", and "Here's me".

Comment: @Araucaria Well, you gotta call it something, and practically anything you might call it is gonna conflict with somebody else's use of the same term. Would you prefer *Theme/Rheme*? ... anyhow, you gotta decide whether you want to deal in the first instance with semantic (thematic) or syntactic or pragmatic roles, and adjust the two leftovers to suit what you're up to.

Comment: @StoneyB I'd like the syntactic one ('cuz that's what I reckon a Subject is all about, the syntax). I don't necessarily disagree, I just, hmmm ...

Comment: @Araucaria Note, by the way, that the terms *theme, topic, subject, object* are all locative metaphors!

Comment: @Araucaria 'Kay, you can call it a Subject - so enlarge your notion of Subject to embrace locatives or narrow your notion of Nominative to exclude some Subjects, or both, or something else. What the sentence means and how it means it are both pretty clear--all we're blathering about is how to describe them.

Answer (score 2):

Verb agreement would point to "me" being the subject:

“And up here in the corner **is me**” vs “And up there in the corner **are us**".

Accusative "me and "us" are the 'normal' forms here, the absurdly formal nominative "I" and "we" also being possible.

But only the nominative "I" would be possible in the non-inverted equivalent:

"I am up here in the corner".

The PP "up here in the corner" would then be a locative predicative complement.

Comment: *Up here in the corner is them* seems to work for my BE ear... Hmmm, not sure yet.

Comment: I'd be more likely to say "And up there in the corner is us," but *be* is notoriously irregular and this question is ample demonstration that that irregularity extends beyond its mere conjugation.

Comment: 'Possible ... but absurdly formal' is getting extremely close to a contradiction in terms. I usually go with 'Applying Orwell's Sixth, _unacceptable_'.

Answer (score 1):

> And up here in the corner is me

**Answer**

'me' is the subject of the sentence. It doesn't comply with standard grammar but it is idiomatic use and that is what it is.

A grammarian would say, *And up here in the corner am I.*

**Reasoning**

**1.**

*Up here in the corner is John.*

This can be inverted to make:

*John is up here in the corner.*

**2.**

Now try the same procedure with 'me'

*Up here in the corner is Me.*

*Me is up here in the corner.*

**3.** The final sentence above is typical of children's speech when they are learning or of adults when they are being 'cute'.

Example: *Me want some more sweeties.*

The child is clearly using 'me' as the subject of the sentence. It's not correct grammar but that's what it is -- the subject.

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong, but I'm not sure about your evidence. I don't believe that kids actually say that!

Comment: Okay. Here's some cast-iron evidence: Child Language
 By Jean Stilwell Peccei  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BguCc7YF0mUC&pg=PA95&dq=%22me+want%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCGoVChMI-OOC-ZCLyQIVSGsUCh37fgON#v=onepage&q=%22me%20want%22&f=false

Comment: @Araucaria this brings up the whole "It is me." "It is I" debate.  Assuming your sentence were actually spoken by someone, I think Chasly is right that it would be idiomatic, which means it's not gonna play by the rules.

Comment: If I'm outside on your doorstep and I call out "It's me", that isn't an accident slip on my part. It's the normal Standard English way to confirm my identity to someone who knows me but can't see me.

Comment: @BillJohnstone - In that case 'it' is the subject. However there is no 'it' in the sentence "Here, in the corner is me"  See the answer by mikki1970 and the reply by Araucaria.  The correct grammar would be 'Here in the corner am I'.

Comment: I made no reference at all to 'subject'! I was trying to make the point that accusative "me" is perfectly normal in places where the very formal nominative "I" would be technically correct. Equally, accusative "me" is okay in the OP's example. See what I mean?

Comment: @michael_timofeev The it's me/I is about Predicative Complements though, not Subjects :) It's related, but different, I think.

Comment: @BillJohnstone - If you make no reference to 'subject' then you are off-topic because the original question was "...what is the Subject of the sentence?"  I have answered and said that the subject is 'me'.

Comment: Wake up, chasly from UK! The point about accusative "me" vs "I" is perfectly valid, particularly as it was raised by the OP. I also said in my reply that "me" is the subject, so what are you arguing about?

Answer (score 1):

A different approach. Let's delete words that clearly aren't the subject and don't chance the form of the sentence:

> And up here in the corner is me

*'And'* clearly isn't the subject, and *'in the corner'*, as *'the corner'*, being preceded by *'in'* clearly isn't the subject, doesn't contain the subject. That leaves us with:

> Up here is me

Now, I think this may in fact the same construction as *'Here is me'* or *'Here I am'*. If it's different, then *'up here'* makes *'here'* a straight noun, but not the subject.

That leaves us with *'here'* and *'me'*.

Re *'here'*, see [What part of speech does “here” have in “I am here”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111058/what-part-of-speech-does-here-have-in-i-am-here) - TLDR, *'here'* is either:

- an adverb, or
- a proximal deictic locative predicate

So that leaves us with *'is'* (nope), or *'me'*. I'd settle on 'me' as the subject. Perhaps it should be *'And up here in the corner am I'*

If you want examples of similar construction of this peculiar inversion of word ordering:

- *'Here stand I'*
- *'That say you!'*
- *'And up here in the corner is an apple'*

Removing the inversion, it's simply *'And I am up here in the corner'*

Comment: Well, *Here* might be a locative predicate in one sentence and a Locative Complement in the same one, and a Subject in another and a Post-modifier in a noun phrase in another. Some grammars may say it's an adverb (It isn't). But being a "deictic locative predicate" and being an "adverb" and being a "Subject" are  different things ... Being one of them doesn't stop you being another necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as saying "It is me up here in the corner." - "me" is the subject.

Comment: But I think, in *it is me up here in the corner* the Subject is *it*, not *me*! We can show this by making a question. The verb will invert with the Subject: "**Is it** me up here in the corner?" So I'm not sure the sentences are exactly the same :-)

Answer (score 0):

We might need to consider the possibility of an elided subject.

Let's start with a simple and unsurprising utterance:

> That's me.

This sentence works in any English dialect that allows the complement to take an objective form.   It even stands as an argument for using the label *oblique* in preference to *objective*.   The "me" is not an object, but it is part of the predicate.   The subject, of course, is the demonstrative pronoun "that".

Person and number are irrelevant in the complement.   "That's me", "that's you", "that's him", "that's us", and "that's them" are also simple and unsurprising.   They all work with the subject "that" and the verb "is".

Adding prepositional modifiers is easy:

> That up here in the corner is me. 
>   Up here in the corner, that's me.

At this point, the demonstrative property of the pronoun is redundant.   We have modifiers that carry a locative semantic.   Other than marking that there is a subject, "that" doesn't have a job to do.   This could be sufficient explanation for an elision:

> <strike>[That]</strike> up here in the corner is me.

In turn, elision explains an otherwise bizarre flexibility in the verb's grammatical number:

> <strike>[That]</strike> up here in the corner is us. 
>   <strike>[Those]</strike> up here in the corner are us.

The verb "to be" retains its normal use and behavior as the copula.   The complement "me" simply specifies what [that] is.   Different dialects can have different preferences regarding the choice between [that] and [those] without needing a further grammatical explanation.   The implication that such prepositional phrases need something to modify is satisfied by the existence of an understood, unwritten subject.

An elided subject isn't the only possible explanation.   However, as explanations go, this one is simple, clear, and productive.

Comment: +1 From me. Sounds very plausible and similar to what I've been thinking more recently. Don't know if it's right though!

Comment: I don't know, either.  I'm not sure that elision can be proven.  The evidence that we really want is, by the very nature of the assumption, missing.  The best I can do is justify the assumption and tentatively accept it until something better comes along.  Alternatives like discarding the notion that a clause requires a subject or the notion that a subjective/oblique form distinction exists certainly don't seem better.