# Why does it matter what the subject is?

Tags: grammar, subjects

I see a lot of questions asking "what is the subject"? ([This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286649/whats-the-subject-in-and-up-here-in-the-corner-is-me), for example.)

Why does it matter, practically, what the subject is? How does knowing the subject give more information than just knowing what the sentence *means*?

In the linked example,

> And up here in the corner is me.

My understanding is that this sentence is being said by a person and that person is saying that they are up in a corner.

What if the subject is "here in the corner"? What would that tell me?

What if the subject is "me"? What would that tell me?

Comment: Good question. It wouldn't tell you a thing if you didn't have a use for the concept of "subject". It might tell you something about how subjects work, or don't work, though; if you're interested in that stuff. Otherwise, you're entirely correct.

Comment: For thousands of years, people have used language to communicate without having any well-developed notion of parts of speech or components of a sentence. They learn how to form sentences by example and by a general sense of what goes with what to produce a coherent expression that makes sense to other people. But label-based identification of things like subjects, verbs, and objects is of particular interest and value to analysts of language, not to everyday speakers (or even to writers).

Comment: The answer that deserves upvoting, in my opinion, is StoneyB's, which I don't think anyone can easily improve on. My response (like John Lawler's) is simply a comment; I wouldn't like to submit it as a full and serious answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is of no use at all to users of a language as users. You can use a language your entire life without knowing what a Subject is, just like you can live your entire life without knowing anything about metabolism.

But teachers trying to explain to a learner ***why*** a particular expression is wrong or ***why*** a particular expression requires a different form, or programmers trying to develop algorithms for translating from one language to another with a very different syntax, need a 'metalanguage' for talking about how language works. *Subject* is a basic term in that metalanguage; and the question you linked is a question about linguistic theory dealing with an 'edge case' where the standard terminology seems to obscure understanding instead of promoting it.